# Getting Input from electret microphone max4466

Tags: python-3.x, microphone

I want to get input from an electret microphone on the raspberry pi 3 in python 3.  The electret microphone is max4466 from Adafriut.  VCC is plugged into 5.ou, GND is plugged into GND, and OUT is plugged  into GPIO 11.  I have GPIO 11 set for input, but all I get are 0's.  What should I do to get input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MAX4466 is an amplifier with analog outputs, not digital ones and zeroes. The GPIO pins are purely digital and can't accept an analog input. In order to digitize the output from a microphone, you need to hook it up to an analog-to-digital converter (ADC). Adafruit sells little ADC boards to help you do this. The ADC digital output would hook up to your GPIO on the Raspberry Pi.

Here's a link to learn about ADCs from Adafruit:

https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-analog-to-digital-converters/overview

Comment: I am interested in using this same device with a Raspberry Pi Pico, which is already capable of ADC. I am looking for resources for processing the output data from the device in MicroPython. Do you know any good resources?